# Multiple URLs for magento store?

Tags: magento, url, magento-1.7

Quick question-

Noticed a problem on my Magento 1.7. Consider the site http://www.seacadetshipsstore.com/magento/. This site has a sub-store that's `/magento/gearlocker/`. The two should be isolated - if you go to `/magento/gearlocker/`, you shouldn't interact with the generic store at `/magento/` at all.

Here's the problem: the store's base URL is set explicitly to http://www.seacadetshipsstore.com/magento/gearlocker/. When users navigate to http://seacadetshipsstore.com/magento/gearlocker/ (no www), they get redirected to http://www.seacadetshipsstore.com/magento/.

My question is this: if a user navigates to the gearlocker site without www, is there a way to set a second store URL to prevent a redirect? Or would it be easier to control that redirect back to `/magento/gearlocker/`, instead of `/magento/`? Any thoughts, solutions, or references would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I would check for the WWW redirect in the `.htaccess` file.  I am willing to bet there is a rule that looks somewhat like: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^seacadetshipsstore.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://http://www.seacadetshipsstore.com/magento/$1 [R=301,L]`  That would redirect ANYONE even those who went to `http://seacadetshipsstore.com/magento/gearlocker/` to the www regular Magento site

Comment: Thanks for the input @Zak - unfortunately there's nothing like that in magento's .htaccess. All I have is a relative path for `/magento/`. Gearlocker has a separate .htaccess with a relative redirect for `/magento/gearlocker/`, in the same subdirectory as it's copy of magento's `index.php`

Comment: OK ... Have you set permissions correctly for your gearlocker environment?  If the `/var/cache` directory isn't set to `777` , then Magento will store it's cache in `/tmp/cache` so your cache may be preventing the new `Base URL` from being read by way of clearing the wrong directory when you do clear it.  Check both `/tmp` and `/var` for cache folders and remove them (preferably command line) After clearing, set permissions for both `sudo chmod -R 777 var` and `sudo chmod -R 777 tmp`and see if that helps?

Comment: And for good measure, temporarily remove the .htaccess files completely and see what happens.  You are getting a `302` redirect (I checked) So I doubt that's it, but still good to know for sure.

Comment: @Zak I think we're getting a little off the mark here. What I'm trying to achieve is showing the store at both www.scss.com and scss.com - but magento forces the redirect from scss.com to www.scss.com. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: That's normally htacces. I was making the assumption that you copied your regular store to a separated store and DB -> gearlocker; and that it wasn't a fresh install. In the new copy (gearlocker), the permissions set to less than 755 and cache not cleared on said copy (gearlocker) would still call to the 'old' base URL of `/magento` even if it's different in the 'new' database.  If that's not the case, and it is not an htaccess problem, there is no other way Magento will redirect a `BASE_URL`. It's either `DB/CACHE` or `htaccess`. There are no other possibilities on a standard Magento install.

Comment: Have you attempted to correct for this using `.htaccess` file (sort of like the original rewrite cond I posted earlier)?  It might be a little tricky, but I am sure it is possible

Comment: @Zak that's exactly what I did - thanks for your guidance. If you post it as an answer, I'll give you the karma you deserve =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See my comments above.  Thanks @CodeMoose

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^seacadetshipsstore.com 
RewriteRule (.*) http://http://www.seacadetshipsstore.com/magento/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly I believe duplicate urls across multiple stores are not possible without one of the urls being auto incremented with a -1 -2 etc.   Please try modifying one of the url keys and let me know what happens.